# Why hasn't my public/index.html file been removed on GitHub yet even after I've added, committed, and pushed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I ran the following code to make sure that my public/index.html file has been deleted:

```
git rm public/index.html
fatal: pathspec 'public/index.html' did not match any files
```

Then I ran git status:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

This is the case because I ran `git commit -am "Removed"` and pushed to git.
Based on those two pieces of responses, I am betting my file has been removed. I even checked my directory and it's not there.  However, the file is still in my repo.  Git push seemed to have done nothing.

```
[Remove 0cd9c89] Removed public/index.html
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 239 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 public/index.html
*******-MacBook-Air:da_list ****$ git push heroku
Everything up-to-date
*******-MacBook-Air:da_list ****$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: are you sure you're on the right branch?

Comment: @karmajunkie. My goodness, good one.  I wasn't and had to merge and push again.  Should I delete this question since it seems so simple? I've got it to work now.

Comment: happens to me frequently, that's how i know to check it. :)  I'd leave it for some other unsuspecting user...

Comment: @karmajunkie & Tony, it wouldn't be a bad idea to make that comment a proper answer and then accept it so that this question doesn't show up in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @blahdiblah Good idea. Didn't understand before but now I realize the existence of good practices on StackOverflow.

Comment: Since you mention good practices, if @karmajunkie happens by, it would be polite to let him or her answer and be accepted so that credit accrues appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be to make sure that you're on the correct branch.
The next step is to merge that correct branch with the master.